# Redirect user to Google Maps Android application making markers and filling in destination

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is there any way I can redirect the user to the Google Maps application on Android. Then fill out the destination for them and add a few markers. So that if a user wants to know where a store is, they are redirected to the Google Maps application and just has to fill in where they are so that they can easily find the store. Is it possible to pass coordinates from one application to another?

Answer (score 1):

To open a map application with a destination you can use

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:0,0?q="+latitude+","+longitude+"("+destinationNme+")");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```